# How does a CAT 4 radio detector work in passive mode?

Tags: circuit-design, probe, ham-radio, emf, sensing

According to

https://www.radiodetection.com/sites/default/files/Theory-Buried-pipe-manual-V10.pdf

in passive mode a CAT 4 radio detector 'looks' for harmonics produced on the 50/60Hz mains buried lines particularly the 3KHz signals. I suppose this makes sense the 50/60Hz radiation would be of an enormous wavelength to detect even to get the slightest efficiency.

I wondered if anybody knows (not speculate) what probe it might use (coil like a metal detector, Hall sensor , an antenna (whip style) highly unlikely) and what circuit (a radio circuit or perhaps electric field or magnetic field detector)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As your manual says and shows above.

The passive mode uses an Active Amplifier with a bandpass filter and wire antenna that is slightly directional for peak signal. 30 to 3kHz probably.  But very directional on the null.  So it could have 2 wires and two op-amps. (cheap) but in a fancy case.

**It is Passive in the sense, that no Tx is used.**

The antenna could be just a wire that nulls on the source of the pipes or a vertical loop with a gap at the bottom for aiming with a broad beamwidth or two for a differential narrow beamwidth.   The metal conduit can also pickup grid hum and re-radiate or pickup ground current from distribution.

Alternatively, you can borrow my neighbour's cats.
[image]

Spike currents from power subscribers now have far more spike currents in the mA range for each device from an SMPS and these contain many, many harmonics.

E fields would be high impedance 10M from a wire, while H fields would be low impedance from a loop antenna is more likely.

Comment: "So it could have 2 wires and two op-amps. (cheap) but in a fancy case." would that make an instrumentation amplifier difference the 2 signals then amplify?

Comment: It could be one INA with a BPF filter for each channel if orthogonal direction tuning was used comparing peak to null, with some comparator or just one channel.